# Russian slang: "the letter Х"

Tags: узус, сленг

Someone told me that in Russian slang, people ask each other: Kак дела? (How are you?), to which the obvious answer is Хорошо (Good).
But there's another word that starts with "x" and means the opposite (It may be a slur. I think it means "sh*t," but I can't remember the word), so when when someone asks you "как дела?", you can respond with the slang phrase: Буква Х (Letter X).

These are my questions:

Is this legitimate slang, and if so, is it *correct*? What's the other word that starts with "x" that means the opposite of "xорошо"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's a cliché joke.

> — Как дела? — На букву "х", но не "хорошо" // "How are you?" "It's an f-word... and I don't mean 'fine.'"

In Russian, we have the slang swear word *хуёво*, which means "bad", and which, like *хорошо* "well", also starts with the letter *х*.

Comment: The word is too ubiquitous to be called 'slang'. It's just an obscenity.

Comment: The Х word is one of the cornerstones of Russian мат.

Answer (score 3):

http://atkritka.com/221817/

Well, the classic (usual) answer is a bit milder.

— Как дела?
— Спасибо, на букву "х"(хрено́во).

Answer (score -1):

The former (pre-20th century) name of the letter X was хѣръ. This word currently means penis. Похерить means *to break*: иди нахер means *go to hell*. Херово means bad.

The etymology goes as follows: Initially, there was a more obscene, taboo word, хуй, with the same meaning, but later people started using the name of the letter as a euphemism for that word, which, by association, also became obscene.

Comment: Похерить has nothing to do with "хер" in a penis meaning, it's also not break but rather to cross something out, to obliterate, to aniihilate, to lose, if you wish. It relates to the fact that X is used to remove piece of written text.

Comment: *На сіе отвѣчалъ я, что прошу впредь моихъ листковъ къ нему не посылать; ибо я съ благодарностію пріемлю учтивые совѣты, но **херить** и марать сочиненій моихъ никому не позволяю.* [А. С. Шишков. Записки, мнѣнія и переписка адмирала А. С. Шишкова. Томъ II. Домашнія записки (1808-1822)](https://books.google.ru/books?id=-ynlDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP4&hl=en&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false)